# Using angular 2 ajax in ionic 2

Tags: angular, restangular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am running an angular 2 application in ionic 2 and I am trying to get JSON data from a server.  What is the process for making a call to the server and receive JSON so my application can parse it?  Are there any things I should be aware of when making the calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject an instance of `Http` into the element (component or service) where you want to execute the request.

For example with ES6 within a component:

```
(...)
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page3/page3.html'
})
export class Page3 {
  constructor(http) {
    http.get('data.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data;
      }
    );
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

Note that you can also use the `async` pipe. See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html

Don't forget to specify the providers for HTTP into your application class:

```
(...)
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@App({
  template: `
    (...)
  `,
  config: {},
  providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
})
export class MyApp {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Do you import rxjs? I updated my answer. If you comment the http request processing, is the http object correctly injected (i.e. its value not undefined) in the constructor?

Comment: does angular 2 ajax have finally ??